# Exposed Wood Framing Near Firebox

Tags: fireplace

I recently purchased a home built in 1973 that has a fireplace with natural stone tile.

[image: Fireplace with Natural Stone Tile]

There is however, exposed wood framing right outside the firebox which is part of the tile work that was installed. To make this as safe as possible, does putting some cement board and flashing make the most sense to mitigate any safety concerns? Is there a better approach/material to put between the exposed wood and the firebox? We will only use the natural gas logs so the heat will be in a very controlled range.

[image: Exposed Wood Framing]

Comment: That looks like "cultured" stone to me.

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue is that the area isn't flat and to make it flat you do not want to chisel out the thinset over the board because the bottom row could loosen.

I would add some primer to the wood, thinset it to as flat as I can then install some metal flashing over that.   If the area is deeper than the picture you could just install some tiles that would go with your setup but I would want them generally out of view.

Also there is building code on combustables near fireplace.   You have to be further than 2" - which this isn't.   I don't think any inspector near me would OK this so you might as well fix it, as you would probably have to when selling house.   Did your home inspector not catch this?

Comment: The home inspector did not catch this, and even more scary was this house was an AirBnB so I'm sure most renters weren't looking for something like this. I will likely go the route of adding additional tile. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: That is the easiest and will look best - thinset doesn't stick well to 2x lumber so make sure you give it a coating that helps.

Comment: Painting over already dangerous combustibles is not a solution to this issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin - you are having a reading comprehension issue - primer, then thinset, then tile... not just painting over it.

Comment: You provide no airgap. This, combined with the fact the entire construction is probably on a wood frame, is still a firetrap. If US regs are so different to EU, then at least provide where the regs would allow for it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - the air gap is behind the framing.   I am not going looking for code to quote when you are the only person that doesn't know.   This is typical US fireplace and code.   If you want to argue with the code then fine.   When you argue because you can't read my answer right... add that crap somewhere else.

Comment: This site is far too US-centric. I think I'm done with it.

Comment: I installed a few of these zero clearance fireplaces with the approved gas log set they allowed contact but the exposed wood had to be back 4-6” from the opening. The problem with these came when folks removed the gas logs and tried to burn wood. Big no no back then the stacks were single walled just like the vent on the water heater that will melt down with a wood fire. I would probably sink a dozen small screws leaving the head slightly up and cover thinset will probably work here but if not refractory cement or fire clay should work. There doesn’t appear to be any scorching of the wood.

Comment: @EdBeal - gas is a different animal.   Just bought a house that outputs - no kidding - 3 times the BTUs as I have seen before.   You could turn this thing on and not run your heater all winter.   That being said I would be careful about the outside of this thing, I wouldn't be with most gas fireplaces I see.   This one... I wouldn't do too much to it other than cover up the wood, fear being you start ruining the stone work.

Comment: I am not sure of your point as that looks exactly like a zero clearance gas log to me yes some have great heat baffles and even blowers that do heat well while looking nice.